# Unable to use CSS/JS with CodeIgniter PHP Framework

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, google-app-engine, frameworks

It's a very common problem and I looked in to many other SO questions but none of them were able to solve my problem.

The CSS/JS won't load and the site crashes with a 400 (Bad Request) and a 500 (Internal Server Error).

**Project Structure (in Atom Editor):**

[image]

**feedController.php:**

```
<?php if (!defined("BASEPATH")) exit("No direct script access allowed");

class feedController extends CI_Controller {
    public function loadfeed() {
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('footer');
      $this->load->view('feed');
    }
}
```

**feed.php:**

I removed the `<head>` and Css Links and Js script code lines and added them to the header.php file

**header.php:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>
        <?php if(isset($meta_title) && !empty($meta_title)) echo $meta_title; ?>
    </title>

    <?php
    echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    echo link_tag('assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
    echo link_tag('assets/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css');
    echo link_tag('assets/js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css');
    echo link_tag('assets/css/style.css');
    ?>
</head>
```

**footer.php:**

```
<?php ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js')?>"></script>
```

**config.php (Located in application/config/config.php):**

```
//I added localhost as my base_url
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

I believe that is all? Yet, I get a **BLANK WHITE page** with console errors saying Bad Request and Internal Server error (pointing to my header.php file).

**EDIT**

I tried this solutions given below, but now I get a error message on the page saying this:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function link_tag()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\views\header.php
>
> Line Number: 11

**Line Number 11 points to the header.php's echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');**

**EDIT:**

I added:

```
$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->helper('url');
```

to my controller's method and the Page Loaded. However, No Styles or JavaScripts were loaded. **404 Errors** are shown in the console

Comment: did you try `class FeedController extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: is that work for you at the above suggestion? if yes,  i will post an answer.

Comment: @user2352577L Going to try it now

Comment: what url u r using??? is it? `http://localhost/Project/feedController/loadfeed`

Comment: @user2352577L Didn't work. I edited the question with the error that just came up

Comment: where u define this function link_tag()????

Comment: @devpro I use this: http://localhost/codeig/index.php/FeedController/loadfeed

Comment: @devpro I defined them in the header.php's css lines. I have added it to the question mate

Comment: It means work now for loading class, so try to add `<?php $CI &= get_instance(); $CI->load->helper('html');?>` at the top of header.php

Comment: i mean, where u define this function? link_tag() in helper???

Comment: @devpro No I haven't defined it in the helper. I'm a bit confused. Am I supposed to?

Comment: than load the html helper in autoload.php file...

Comment: @user2352577L Which file should I add it to? FeedController?

Comment: i means, load `$this->load->helper('html');` in your controller...

Comment: `application/config/autoload.php` add like this `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');` or   add `<?php $CI &= get_instance(); $CI->load->helper('html');?>` at the top of header.php

Comment: and what happened when u load?

Comment: if still not working, go to view source and check what are the URLs of CSS and JS files...

Comment: and your baseurl should be: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeig/';`

Comment: The URL's show this error: 404 (Not Found) - http://localhost/assets/css/animate.css. Is that the right path? :D @devpro

Comment: @user2352577L I added that to the top of the header and got: "Undefined variable: CI"

Comment: Your controller should only have first letter upper case. `Feedcontroller.php` and class `Feedcontroller extends CI_Controller {}` this is the correct way for codeIgniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding HTML Helper library:

now you need to modify your `base_url()` as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeig/'; // use this
```

**And what you are using?**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

**Why i suggest this:**

As per your comment your css path is:

```
localhost/assets/css/animate.css
```

Which is clearly showing, there is no project folder available in your url. and this should be:

```
localhost/codeig/assets/css/animate.css
```

Comment: BOOM!!! Problem fixed! Thanks man :) One small question, my URL is: http://localhost/codeig/index.php/FeedController/loadfeed. How can I remove the unnecessary '/index.php/FeedController/loadfeed' and just have a clean url like: 'http://localhost/feed.php'?

Comment: @Earthling: for removing index.php, explore this user guide,,, CI explain smartly this: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: @Earthling: glad to help u friend, always love to debug step by step.. :)

Comment: Another small doubt :D After I publish this, what will be my base_url? www.my-domain.com?

Comment: @Earthling: if ENVIRONMENT is development: than use this, else ENVIRONMENT is production than use `$config['base_url'] = "/";` or empty

Answer (score 2):

Change your class name `feedController` to `Feedcontroller` and rename file also.Then try because Linux server return 500 error with this name `feedController`

Comment: Hold on I'll try this now

Comment: Didn't work. I edited the question with the error that just came up

Comment: are u load helper ? $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: I added $this->load->helper('url'); and $this->load->helper('html'); to the controller and the page loaded successfully. BUT CSS and JS files are not found yet. No styling is shown

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh Your controller should only have first letter upper case. `Feedcontroller.php` and class `Feedcontroller extends CI_Controller {}` this is the correct  way for codeIgniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Answer (score -1):

If it's `Codeigniter2`, then we don't need to set `base_url`.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: In Ci2 yes: In codeigniter 3 it is best to not leave it blank because you may run into some errors as many people have come across.